# static-content:deploy not working

Tags: magento2.1.5, static-content, static-content-deploy

I'm **overriding a core JS** file in **my module**. When I run

```
php bin/magento static-content:deploy
```

and refresh the page the JavaScript does not seem to change.

I started tracking the issue. I found that the file loaded in my `pub/static/path_to_my_file` is not updated. According to Magento 2 documentation it should have been updated, which is not happening.

Then after removing the `pub/static` folder design of frontend got ugly even after deploying static-content.

What is the cause and what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is not only your problem. It is kind of weakness or lets say feature should have been implemented in magento 2. It was supposed to work as you explained so well.

The reason you are unable to see the nice and well designed frontend is because you have **deleted `.htaccess`** file, used for establishing **symlinks for static contents**, that is within **`pub/static`** folder.

If you can revert the process or can get it from you git repo ,if you have, then you can create new one similar.

Next time when you want to **deploy** your **particular js just delete your file pub/static/path_to_my_file and reload the browser**. You will see that your new **javascript will take effect** like charm.

Comment: It solved my problem.